# how to create data sub types

Tags: haskell

I want pass a sub data type into function.

An example:

```
data Car a = Ford | Opel | BMW | Mercedes a deriving (Show)

data Mercedes a = SClass a| CClass a| MClass a


myfunc::Car->String
myfunc a = show a ++ " works correctly"
```

but I do:

> myfunc CClass "x"

it says

> not in scope: constructor CClass

Comment: This has multiple errors. "deriving (Show)" should have the "show" capitalised. Your second line seems to be trying to be a data type, but lacks the "data" keyword (probably the cause of your error message). If you did it that way then your types are going to be problematic because you will have "Ford" being of type "Car (Mercedes String)". Tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, you need to use `show` in `myfunc`, i.e. `myfunc a = show a ++ " works correctly"`.

Comment: I want to be able to pass in any car model into one function and the function be able to pattern-match the car model and treat each one differently.

Comment: Looks like you're thinking too "object-oriented", or rather too much in the style of what Java & co. call object-oriented. Examples like this may give a reasonably good insight into the way you're dealing with objects in those languages, but they don't really make much sense as they are. And Haskell has other (and more powerful) ways of doing stuff, you might want to rather write some interesting _programs_ rather than trying to apply OO language example structures to Haskell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To achieve "sub"-types, one has a few options. The first is just to use more `data` types, as you are attempting:

```
data Car a = Ford (Ford a) | Mercedes (Mercedes a) deriving (Show)

data Ford a = ModelT a | Falcon a deriving (Show) -- different Fords models
data Mercedes a = CClass a | SClass a deriving (Show) -- different Mercedes models
```

Note that being a type constructor is different to being a data constructor, so one can't just use `data Car = .. | Mercedes a`:  this is saying that one of the ways to make a `Car String` is just by saying `Mercedes "a"`, it has no correlation with the type called `Mercedes`. Now one can just use a function like:

```
horsepower :: Car a -> Float
horsepower (Ford (ModelT _)) = 1
horsepower (Ford (Falcon _)) = 500
horsepower (Mercedes (CClass _)) = 300
horsepower (Mercedes (SClass _)) = 400
```

And your example would be:

```
myfunc :: Show a => Car a -> String
myfunc a = show a ++ " works correctly"

-- myfunc (Ford (ModelT "A")) => Ford (ModelT "A") works correctly
-- myfunc (Mercedes (CClass "b")) => Mercedes (CClass "b") works correctly
```

---

Another way to allow "subtyping" like this is to use a type class (depending on the specifics, this might be a better option). E.g.

```
class (Show c) => Car c where
    make :: String
    model :: c -> String
    horsepower :: c -> Float
    number_of_seats :: c -> Int
    -- etc.

data Ford a = ModelT a | Falcon a deriving (Show)
instance (Show a) => Car (Ford a) where
    make = "Ford"
    horsepower (ModelT _) = 1
    horsepower (Falcon _) = 500
    -- etc.


data Mercedes a = CClass a | SClass a deriving (Show)
instance (Show a) => Car (Mercedes a) where
    make = "Mercedes"
    horsepower (CClass _) = 300
    horsepower (SClass _) = 400
    -- etc.
```

Your example of `myfunc` might be:

```
myfunc :: (Car c) => c -> String
myfunc c = (make `asTypeOf` c) ++ " " ++ show c ++ " works correctly"

-- myfunc (ModelT "A") => Ford ModelT "A" works correctly
-- myfunc (CClass "b") => Mercedes CClass "b" works correctly
```

---

Also note that one must call functions like `function (Ford (Ford "a"))` (or `function (CClass "a")`) with parenthesis.

Answer (score 5):

First off, you need to define your car type as follows:

```
data Car a = ... | Mercedes (MercedesClass a) | ...

data MercedesClass a = CClass a | ...
```

... and then you can write:

```
myFunc (Mercedes (CClass "x"))
```

Comment: In myFunc I try to pattern match on (CClass a) but it says couldnt match expected type Car a with actual type MercedesClass a

Comment: @peroni_santo You have to pattern match on `Mercedes (CClass a)`

Comment: @peroni_santo in `let v = CClass "x"` a value `v` has type `MercedesClass String`. Then, in `let c = Mercedes v`, a value `c` has type `Car String`.